# How can celebrate the release Wordpress 3.5

Tags: discussion, wordpress.org

3.5 includes a new default theme, Twenty Twelve, which has a very clean and 
New change is a completely re-imagined flow for uploading photos and creating galleries.

What can we do to show our support and appreciation of the [wordpress developers](http://wordpress.org/news/2012/12/elvin/) who contributed to this thing we all love and give this site meaning?

Answer (score 8):

We are doing this already: New features or a new standard theme are opportunities for great questions and answers. On a Q&A site focused on facts, this the best we can and should do.

[image]